# Creating an approval workflow with Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: workflow, content-approval

I have a problem with Sharepoint 2010. For some reason the famous "Sharepoint 2010 - Approval Workflow" is nowhere to be found on the workflow templates and I can't figure out how to create one on the designer. Everywhere I'm looking for it it assumes I already have it out of the box.

The workflow is quite simple, it should do the following

1.- Send mail to approvers

2.- Make approvers either approve or reject the document

3.- If document was approved set is status as approved and send email to the original user

4.- If document was rejected set is status as rejected and send email to the original user

This raises the following questions:

a.- If I do this manually do I need to set in the Library Settings "Require content approval for submitted items?" or will this cause a conflict between the workflow in sharepoint and the one I've created

b.- Do I need to create a column for approval or is there a way to reuse the Approval Status system column?

c.- How do I send an email to the user who started the workflow?

I'm very confused with this and online help doesn't look very helpful, so if someone can help I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the workflows aren't showing up, I'd make sure that the Workflows feature is activated for your site collection.
Site Settings -> Site Collection Features -> Workflows